# tcp socket, select tells writable, but write() blocks

Tags: python, c, sockets, select, tcp

I wrote a little tcp socket server program, using select() to check if a client socket is writable. If the client is writable, I will write data to it.

The client is written in Python, for testing only, it connect to the server, and never read from the connect.

The result is, server write() finally blocks.

**Server(C):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int serv_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    const char *ip = "0.0.0.0";
    int opt = 1;
    int port = 7000;
    if(argc > 2){
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons((short)port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr.sin_addr);

    serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    setsockopt(serv_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));
    bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(serv_sock, 1024);

    printf("server listen on port: %d\n", port);

    int sock = accept(serv_sock, NULL, NULL);
    printf("accepted\n");

    while(1){
        fd_set w_set;
        FD_ZERO(&w_set);
        int maxfd = sock;
        FD_SET(sock, &w_set);
        int ret = select(maxfd + 1, NULL, &w_set, NULL, NULL);
        if(ret < 0){
            if(errno == EINTR){
                continue;
            }else{
                printf("select error! %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        char buf[128 * 1024];
        if(FD_ISSET(sock, &w_set)){
            printf("write begin\n");
            int n = write(sock, buf, sizeof(buf));
            printf("write %d\n", n);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Client(Python):**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7000))
```

**Output:**

```
$ gcc a.c; ./a.out 
server listen on port: 7000
accepted
write begin
write 131072
write begin
write 131072
write begin
write 131072
write begin
write 131072
write begin
write 131072
write begin
```

My qustion is: **why would write() operation blocks even if select tells writable?** The manual of select() says:

> A  file descriptor  is  considered  ready  if  it  is possible to
>   perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without
>   blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Select() doesnt know how many bytes you are going to try to write, it only knows that the socket's outgoing-data buffer isn't full.

If you want write() not to block, set the socket to non-blocking mode.

Comment: If I want to send 1000 bytes, and there is only 10 bytes space, shouldn't write() return with 10 bytes sent(return value = 10)?

Comment: I mean partial write. Is it only applied on non-blocking socket? Any references have a clear point about this?

Comment: It could return 10 and return, but unless you set the socket to non-blocking mode, it's not guaranteed to do that.

Comment: This may be the truth, any references appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver's TCP buffer will finally be filled with data sent by the sender so that it advertises a zero-sized window to notify the sender that "I have no space left to hold your data, stop now".